# Is it safe to commit the Gopkg.lock file?

Tags: go, build, version-control

I am new to **Go** and was wondering whether it's safe to commit the **Gopkg.lock** file in a VCS?

Comment: What aspect of safety are you concerned about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you **should** commit it. This file makes much less sense if everybody has his own version.

It makes the build reproducible from one developer to another, and more importantly it ensures the deployment build environnment won't use an unexpected set of dependency versions.